# Get the username from a linkedin REST API call

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using linkedin's Oauth2 stuff to authenticate and incorporate users info on a site I'm working on. I'd like to be able to use the REST API and using the querystring /people/~:(id,site-standard-profile-request) etc[assuming the person with an answer knows the API], to be able to get the user's linkedin username.

The reason I want this is so that I can use a link to view the users profile like this: linkedin.com/in/(username)

The /in/ works for both logged in and non-logged in viewers which is amazing for developers that like simple easy ways of doing things.

I hope that someone out there at least has an answer. I cannot find anything along the lines of 'username' in their API documentation. They might not offer it through this service, but it can't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a username field offered via the Linkedin People API. The default response from `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~` will return a `site-standard-profile-request/url`. So that will get the logged in users profile url, or substituting the tilde with a id will retrieve somebody elses profile url. Using this url will accomplish the same thing as what your after.

Comment: Thanks gdp, I appreciate your answer. However this still just returns the public url to the user's page. Linkedin probably does not offer what I am looking for. 

I just kind of assumed they would since /in/username is a thing...